# SharePoint Discussion Board "Last updated" field is not updated any more

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-discussion-board

On of our SharePoint users informed me today about a strange behavior of a discussion board on one of his sites.

Normally the standard "subject" view of an discussion list has a field named "Last updated" showing the date and time of the last post within the corresponding thread. On the discussion board of our user this field is never set to the date/time of the last post but stays on the date/time when the thread was started.

The site on which the discussion board is located was created from a custom web site template which includes the empty discussion board.

To narrow this problem I created a second discussion board on the same site, with the result that it sets the Last updated field correctly.

Any suggestions why the Last updated field doesn't update any more?

Answer (score 1):

Has the view been modified to use the creation date instead? I've had more than a few problems with people accidentally modifying the shared view of a list instead of the personal view...

Comment: No, it's a standard oob discussion board without any modifications.

Answer (score 0):

We've experienced the same behavior. No solution, but the Last Modified field seems to do the same.